# String is not convert to NSURL [SWIFT]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsurl

Why am I getting this error? I paste the code, my first attemp broke a thread when in runtime. Gosh, now I see why the first question apple recruiters ask CS students is do you know apple code, or 'swift'...(meh)

The error says - lastPathComponent is unavailable: Use lastPathComponent on NSURL instead

```
    // get a list of all the png files in the app's images group
    let paths = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType(
        "png", inDirectory: nil) 

    // get image filenames from paths
    for path in paths  {
        if !path.lastPathComponent.hasPrefix("AppIcon") { //error
            allCountries.append(path.lastPathComponent)  //error
        }
    }
```

Attempt 1:

```
    for path in paths as [AnyObject] {
        if !path.lastPathComponent.hasPrefix("AppIcon") {
            allCountries.append(path.lastPathComponent)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was due to the fact, that I was not able to use the original Xcode 5 for my deployment on my iphone

Comment: Thanks for your email. The apps were written in Swift 1.2 and there are MANY breaking changes between Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0. Xcode 7 requires Swift 2.0.

Comment: You can still use lastPathComponent with NSString. Just cast (self as NSString).lastPathComponent or add an extension to your project so you don't need to change your code at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the URL related API

```
if let imageURLs = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLsForResourcesWithExtension("png", subdirectory: nil) {
  // get image filenames from paths
  for url in imageURLs  {
    if !url.lastPathComponent!.hasPrefix("AppIcon") {
      allCountries.append(url.lastPathComponent!)
    }
  }
}
```

or a bit "Swiftier"

```
if let urls = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLsForResourcesWithExtension("png", subdirectory: nil) {
  allCountries = urls.filter {$0.lastPathComponent!.hasPrefix("AppIcon") == false} .map {$0.lastPathComponent!}
}
```

Comment: nope. I tried that. and it didnt work.

Comment: `if let paths = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLsForResourcesWithExtension( "png", subdirectory: nil){
        
        // get image filenames from paths
        for path in paths as [AnyObject]{
            if !path.lastPathComponent.hasPrefix("AppIcon") {
                allCountries.append(path.lastPathComponent!)
            }
        }
        }`

Comment: don't cast to [AnyObject]. Use the code as it is

Comment: I get the error Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mena to use '!' or '?' for code `if !path.lastPathComponent.hasPrefix("AppIcon")`

Comment: please use my code! There is a exclamation mark after `lastPathComponent`

Comment: ;) I didn't see 'dat

Comment: Swapping an extension with itself is not supported us now an error

Comment: The reason for that error must be somewhere else.